# Error using async in AngularFireObject

Tags: html, angular, typescript, firebase, ionic3

I'm having trouble using async in AngularFireObject. What's the solution?

HomePage.ts:

```
import { AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';

export class HomePage {

     profileData: AngularFireObject<any>;

     constructor(public authProvider: AuthProvider){}

     ionViewWillLoad(){
        // Here is returning the user logged in correctly
        // and passing data.uid as parameter

        this.authProvider.authState().subscribe(data => {
        this.profileData = this.authProvider.getUserProfile(data.uid);
     })
}
```

HomePage.html:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <p>Nome: {{(profileData | async)?.nome}}</p>
</ion-content>
```

AuthProvider.ts:

```
export class AuthProvider {
  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  getUserProfile(data: any) {
    return this.afDatabase.object(`user-profile/${data.uid}`); // returns AngularFireObject

  }
```

The following error is returned when I try to use async on an AngularFireObject.

```
Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
    at invalidPipeArgumentError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:22387:12)
    at AsyncPipe._selectStrategy (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:23798:15)
    at AsyncPipe._subscribe (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:23780:31)
    at AsyncPipe.transform (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:23754:22)
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ng:///AppModule/HomePage.ngfactory.js:132:73)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14730:21)
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13866:14)
    at callViewAction (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14211:21)
    at execComponentViewsAction (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14143:13)
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13867:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `this.profileData` is technically not an `Observable`until, `this.authProvider.authState()` has been resolved. That is why the `async` pipe throws an error because it is expecting an `Observable` right from the start. 
What you can do is, you can use a `.switchMap` to transform the Observable, something like this:

```
this.profileData = this.authProvider.authState().switchMap(data => {
    return this.authProvider.getUserProfile(data.uid);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The **valueChanges ()** method returns an **Observable**, the error does not occur but shows no value.

The records are saved correctly, I do not understand why it does not display the value.

**AuthProvider.ts:**

```
getUserProfile(data: any) {
    // return observable
    return this.afDatabase.object(`user-profile/${data.uid}`).valueChanges();

}
```

**HomePage.ts:**

```
profileData: Observable<any>;

  ionViewWillLoad() {
    this.authProvider.authState().subscribe(data => {
      this.profileData = this.authProvider.getUserProfile(data.uid);
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HomePage.ts

```
import { AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
export class HomePage {

         profileData: AngularFireObject<any>;
         item: any = {};
         constructor(public authProvider: AuthProvider){}

         ionViewWillLoad() {
            this.authProvider.authState().subscribe(data => {

            this.itemRef = this.afDatabase.object(`user-profile/${data.uid}`);
            this.itemRef.valueChanges()
            .subscribe(item => {
                this.profileData  = item;
            });

         })
    }
```

HomePage.html

```
<ion-content padding>
  <p>Nome: {{ profileData?.nome }}</p>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: This error is returned: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _this.itemRef.valueChanges is not a function
TypeError: _this.itemRef.valueChanges is not a function